# Where to access DataContext in WinRT XAML UserControl

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I've got `UserControlViewModel` which raises an event:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> StuffDone;
```

An object of `UserControlViewModel` is created and initialised inside `MainPageViewModel`:

```
this.userControlViewModel = new UserControlViewModel();
```

`MainPageViewModel` is the View-Model for `MainPage`.

In MainPage.xaml, I've got the following code to place `UserControlView` `UserControl` in `MainPage` and initialise its `DataContext`:

```
<views:UserControlView DataContext="{Binding userControlViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False"></views:UserControlView>
```

So far everything works fine.

Now I'd like to subscribe to `StuffDone` event inside `UserControlView`. The first thing occurred to me is to do it inside `Loaded` event-handler of `UserControlView`; however, the `DataContext` at that point is still `null`. Scanning the rest of `UserControl` events gave me no clue at all.

So, where is the right place to get the `DataContext` and subscribe to its events?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Painful.  There is no event, and no overriding metadata on the DataContext dependency property.  Go home, Microsoft, you're drunk.  This guy has a solution here:  http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2013/01/23/datacontextchanged-event-for-winrt.aspx  Hacky.

Comment: I have done this before and it works fine for me. But I used "Mode=TwoWay". In the Loaded event of UserControl, I can access ViewModel (of course you have to cast DataCotext to your ViewModel to access it)

Comment: @Sach, done what exactly? what [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) suggested? If it's something else, can you please provide some example on what you've done?

Comment: @Will, thanks for the link. I've tried the approach provided, with some modifications from my side, and it worked. You can post that as an answer and I'll add my modifications. If there is no better approach I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Add your own and I'll upvote it. :/

Comment: It's very lengthy code I have, what I have done was, I have a ViewModel where it contains an event and I bonded static instance of that ViewModel to my user control. After that, inside user control I added handler for the event and when I fire event inside ViewModel, handler in user control will get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: [DataContextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx) event is supported in WinRT for Windows 8.1. Use the following only if you're coding against WinRT for Windows 8, or whatever platform that does not support `DataContextChanged`.

Seems like there is no straightforward way to do it and the workaround suggested by [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) on his comment is the simplest way to go.

Below is my version of the workaround which works for me:

In IDataContextChangedHandler.Generic.cs:

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public interface IDataContextChangedHandler<in T> where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        void DataContextChanged(T sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    }
}
```

In DataContextChangedHelper.Generic.cs:

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public sealed class DataContextChangedHandler<T> where T : FrameworkElement, IDataContextChangedHandler<T>
    {
        private readonly DependencyProperty internalDataContextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "InternalDataContext",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(T),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, DataContextChanged));

        private static void DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as T;

            if (control == null) { return; }

            control.DataContextChanged(control, e);
        }

        public void Bind(T control)
        {
            control.SetBinding(this.internalDataContextProperty, new Binding());
        }
    }
}
```

In UserControlView.xaml.cs:

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public sealed partial class UserControlView : IDataContextChangedHandler<UserControlView>
    {
        private readonly DataContextChangedHandler<UserControlView> handler = new DataContextChangedHandler<UserControlView>();

        public UserControlView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.handler.Bind(this);
        }

        public void DataContextChanged(UserControlView sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var viewModel = e.NewValue as UserControlViewModel;

            if (viewModel == null) { return; }

            viewModel.SomeEventRaised += (o, args) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TheOtherState", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I prefer this approach: http://amrreda.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/winrt-datacontext-changed-event-and-trigger/